# Question Asker isn't highlighted in comments when question was migrated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, highlighting

It seems that if a question is migrated, the asker's name doesn't get highlighted when he/she posts comments.  For example:

[GUI FTP program capable of using public/private keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/43635/gui-ftp-program-capable-of-using-public-private-keys)

See Sarteck comments on the question and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until they associate their accounts and the system knows who is actually asking the question, it won't show.

DisplayName isn't something unique, but the UserID is, and while the question and comment both share the same DisplayName, without the unique  user ID, you can't be certain that they're one and the same.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  So, does it work if they have associated their accounts?

Comment: Wait and see, but it should do.

Answer (score 1):

The openids have to be properly associated between the two sites. This is done via the "accounts" tab on the user page.

Once the accounts are associated, the user will re-own any migrated questions.